# Change the class of a hyperlink depending on its text

Tags: javascript, css, disqus

I'm trying to set up a web page that contains links to pages that have Disqus comments on them. There is specific guidance on adding a comment count to a link [that Disqus provides](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624), but it's not great. You are limited to using an `<a>` element, and it replaces the text of the hyperlink with new text.

So, if I create a hyperlink like this on my site:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/posts/1234#disqus_thread">linktext</a>
```

after the page loads, it looks like this:

```
<a class="link-processed" href="http://mysite.com/posts/1234#disqus_thread">
   (1 and 0)
</a>
```

(note that, by default, the replacement text would be "1 comment and 0 reactions" but I have modified the default text to return just the numbers, in brackets.)

When the text of the hyperlink is "(0 and 0)" I'd like to hide the link. When it is anything else, I'd like to replace the text of the link with an image link (little speech bubble or similar.)

I am thinking that the way to do this might be to use a couple of classes. I'll apply the first class (hidelink) by default, and use javascript to apply the second class to the `<a>` element.

However, now I'm stuck. Javascript is not my native domain. This seems like it should be a straightforward task, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are your browser requirements? If you're using IE8+ (or most other browsers) you could use `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName` to get all processed links and then check if its text match your condition:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.link-processed');
for(var i = 0, size = elems.length; i < size; i++)
{
    if(elems[i].innerText === "(0 and 0)")
    {
        //0 and 0. Do something
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using jQuery, you could simply select all elements that contain "0 and 0", using the pseudo class `:contains`:

```
$("a:contains('0 and 0')")
```

Comment: I'll take a look at the jQuery suggestion, since I know we have that on the site.

Comment: OK, I tried the jQuery. It works on other page elements, but not on the target element, I suspect because the other javascript run by Disqus runs after the jQuery call. Is there a way I can force the jQuery call to run last (or at least, after the other code?)

Comment: I thought I might be able to use the "defer" method for my javascript, since all the OOTB DisQus code is run async. Mucked around with it for a bit, then basically rewrote their javascript to make my life a lot easier. The suggestions above do not work in my circumstances, because of the async nature of Disqus javascript, but the question is now irrelevant as I have worked around the issue.